# How to write full path in batch script if there is space (windows)?

Tags: windows, batch-file

this is my batch script which work fine if there is no space in folder path.

```
    @echo off
    for /d /r "N:\work\New folder (3)" %%a in (*)  do (
      copy /y "N:\work\abc.txt" "%%a"
    )
```

i could use `CD N:\work\New folder (3)` but i have to edit a bunch of other batch file.

Comment: How is this failing if there is a space in the folder name?

Comment: My bad. i was trying different example to test. problem solved